# Best practices of creating Model class of MVC

Tags: ios, swift, oop, model-view-controller

I'm going to create an own version of Minesweeper game, and I'm wondering, what is the best way to create a class of cell game?

I have two versions:

1.

```
class GameCell: UIButton {
    var bombCountAround: Int = 0
    var isBomb: Bool = false
}
```

2.

```
class GameCell {
    var bombCountAround: Int = 0
    var isBomb: Bool = false
    var button: UIButton!
}
```

Which one is better way of OOP or MVC coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t recommend either of those two patterns.

One’s model should be free of any view references (i.e. it should have no UIKit references). You don’t want to conflate your view (things like buttons, images, chrome, etc., that you see on screen) and models (an abstract representation of the entire board, representing which squares have bombs and which don’t and which squares are still hidden and which have been un-hidden).

FWIW, I’d also personally be inclined to leave `bombCountAround` a property that is computed by the `Board` for a given row and column. It’s not really a property of any given square, but rather the relationship between various squares. Theoretically you could have a property to capture this, to save having to recalculate it on the fly, but the computational overhead of looking at the eight surrounding cells is so minimal, that it’s really not necessary.

---

By way of example, I might have an object for a particular square on the board:

```
struct Square {
    var isBomb: Bool
    var isHidden: Bool
    var hasUserFlagged: Bool
}
```

This model represents everything we’ll need to know about the cell when we get around to creating the views. Specifically, is the square really a bomb or not, is the square still hidden (e.g. the user hasn’t tapped on it at all), or has the user planted a flag there to represent that they think there is a bomb there or not.

By the way, notice that I’m not using `Cell` anywhere in the model name, as that often connotes a UIKit object, e.g. a collection view cell. The model shouldn’t be worried about implementations of the view (i.e. whether you are using collection view cells, or just buttons in stack views, or just image views with constraints). And `Cell` implies a type of visual element, not an abstract square on a board.

That having been said, we probably want a structure to represent the entire board of all of these squares maybe a `Board` that represents the whole game board:

```
struct Board {
    private var squares: [[Square]]

    init(width: Int, height: Int, bombCount: Int) {
        // build the squares array of array of `Square`, setting a certain number to have bombs
    }
}

extension Board {
    func isBomb(column: Int, row: Int) -> Bool {
        // look up to see if the `Square` at that row and column is a bomb or not
    }

    func howManyBombsNear(column: Int, row: Int) -> Int {
        // calculate how many nearby bombs there are
    }
}
```

Now, this this might not be the right model. Maybe you’d want to separate out the initial setup of where the bombs are from the game-time stats about what has been unhidden by the user and what has flags. That’s up to you.

But the take-away message is that the model should be completely free of any view related types. The view is completely abstracted away from the model, so that you can implement this however you want for the platform in question (e.g. your non-Catalyst macOS target might use completely different set of views than your iOS/iPadOS/tvOS targets).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very useful answer for me! I have just a small question, how to connect instance of UIButton and this model (Square)? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: The controller would do this. So, when the game starts, you’d create your `Board` model and your view controller would add all the buttons associated with that. Every time the user taps on a button, your controller would say “OK, let’s look at the model and see what I should do in response to tapping on this particular button associate with this particular row and column within the board.”

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating these `GameCell`s inside your ViewController, I think the **nature** of a `GameCell` is a button that accepts user interaction and will respond with updating the game board. So I will say the first approach seems more reasonable.

But if you are creating your `GameCell`s inside your Model and then use them to create the UI, I believe you may use something like your second approach but your `GameCell` should be a property of your `Button`.